# CPF1922 variable not found even if the variable exists

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a variable `YEAR OF R1234H01-O`, which is missing if I try to display while debugging even though it is clearly found in the program. It seems like any variable with `OF` wont work. Any idea why?

Note: I wrapped this variable in a single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are debugging an OPM COBOL program using STRISDB.

If your program was compiled with the NOUNREF option, unreferenced fields are not generated into the program.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't know that is the NOUNREF option. Thanks for answering even though I didn't manage to show alot of details.